# Apache Sling resumable upload

Tags: java, file-upload, download, jcr, sling

I wonder, is there support for resumable file upload/download in Apache Sling.

I want to build web content repository system (based on JCR repository) with java client. Something similar to Dropbox and Google Drive. And it should be able to continue file transferring after network errors or user pause request.

And if there is no support for this, can someone suggest a solution for resumable file upload/download with JCR repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is resumable upload out-of-the-box in Sling - or any other Java framework by that matter. What I would do is split large files in chunks on the client and then upload them sequentially.

You can have a look at the [ResumableHttpUploadTask - Apache 2 License](http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn-history/r189/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/client/uploader/ResumableHttpUploadTask.java) for a pure HTTP, single-file approach.

Comment: I suspected that. But there is WebDAV implementations with builtin resumable upload capability. http://www.webdavsystem.com/javaserver/doc/resumable_upload
So, I thought there is something similar in Sling.
There is also a nice explanation how resumable upload works based on Content-Range and Range headers.

Comment: That's interesting to see. Based on that, I would simply roll my own (Sling) servlet which handles those headers.

Comment: If you create such a servlet, contributing it to Sling would be great!

Comment: Hmmm. An interesting proposal. But such servlet will place a certain limitations to client implementation. Such as sending proper headers and content to server. But I think there is no escape :)

Answer (score 2):

There is currently (2013) an effort in Sling to add resumable uploads: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-2707